# What's the meaning of evaluating addEventListener as conditon in if statement?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

what does code like this means ?

```
if(some_domElement.addEventListener)
{
   //rest of the code...
   //rest of the code...
   //rest of the code...
   //rest of the code...
}
```

I'm trying to understand the meaning of addEventListener inside if condition...
can someone give me an example please.

Comment: The if statement in plain English: "Does the variable have `addEventListener` property? If yes, do this."

Comment: It's pretty much just testing that the property exists using _truthiness_.

Comment: My question is there more code to this? Because it could be an outdated example seeing if it uses different ways to bind event listeners to an element.

Comment: Did you try running a simple example of this pattern or play with the code at all to see what it does? Try running it with two objects, one wth the property `addEventListener` and one without, and I bet all will be made clear.